# Receiving gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer when gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: returned NO

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view that has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. That same view also contains a `UIScrollView`.

When the user pans over the ScrollView, I return NO in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`, to make sure that the ScrollView's gesture recognizer takes over the gesture.

However, I still receive the `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` message. It is easy to fix, I simply need to return NO in `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`, but I was wondering if it is normal to receive this message after returning NO to `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`.

**Code**

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:0x%x - return NO", (int)gestureRecognizer);
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer:0x%x shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:0x%x", (int)gestureRecognizer, (int)otherGestureRecognizer);
    return YES;
}
```

**Output**

```
2013-03-04 11:30:14.876 XXXX[99271:19d03] gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:0x9d6c380 - return NO
2013-03-04 11:30:14.876 XXXX[99271:19d03] gestureRecognizer:0x9d6c380 shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:0xbb75240
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this behaviour is ok.
From the following reference of `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` method from official doc Discussion:

> This method is called when a gesture recognizer attempts to transition out of the `UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible` state. Returning NO causes the gesture recognizer to transition to the `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed` state.

This clearly indicates that it will not prevent the gesture recognizer but it will make the transition to `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed` state of respective gesture recognizer. So other delegate methods will be called as normal.